# How to Bind Data Source to Button Click Event in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

How do i bind a datasource to a button ,when i run this the grid view does not populate.

C# CODE

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the wrong property.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSourceObject = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: still getting no value

Comment: @JD1919 Then you haven't given us enough information. For example, what's the select command of the data source? What data exists in the database?

Comment: when i test the query in the sqldatasource , it executes normally.